# Automatically fill in values in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I achieve the following in Excel behavior?

`A1 = 123` and in `A2 = 56`.

56 fits 2.19x times in in 123, e.g., =123/56. It fits via the sequence 56, 56 and 11 (=MOD(123,56)). Now how do I obtain that those values are shown in cells C1...C7

```
C1: 56
C2: 56
C3: 11
C4: 0
C5: 0
C6: 0
C7: 0
```

And when A1 is 173

```
C1: 56
C2: 56
C3: 56
C4: 5
C5: 0
C6: 0
C7: 0
```

Et cetera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it via an IF cause

```
 A1 Start value  B1 Divisor
A2:   =IF(A1>=$B$1;A1-$B$1;IF(B1=$B$1;$B$1;0))  B2: =IF(A2<$B$1;A2;$B$1)
```

then pull down as far as you need and in column B you have all you need

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In **C1** enter:

```
 =A2
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(SUM($C$1:C1)=$A$1,"",IF(SUM($C$1:C1)<$A$1,MIN($A$1-SUM($C$1:C1),C1)))
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This solution does not use helper cells, has simple and short expressions, and uses the question's exact cell distribution.

1. Set C1 to

   ```
   =MIN(A1, A2)
   ```
2. Set C2 to

   ```
   =MIN($A$1-SUM($C$1:C1), $A$2)
   ```
3. Now drag/copy C2 down as long as you want.

   [image]

Comment: Beautiful formula! .............way better than mine........... *(+1)*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thank you! 